# Google Spreadsheets Index-Match

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match

I'm having difficulty writing the correct formula to find the value of a cell at the intersection of dynamically chose row and column. The choices for row and column are populated by data validation.

A very simple version using a colour mixing example can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsOxG6LF9b4XdEliSlMzQl94UnJWOF9IZVducHRNS1E&usp=sharing

Which uses the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:D4; MATCH(B9,A2:A4,0); MATCH(C9,B1:D1,0))
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this the best method for finding data in a simple table using multiple criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument just needs to be the array you are indexing, and therefore shouldn't include the column and row headers:

`=INDEX(B2:D4;MATCH(B9;A2:A4;0);MATCH(C9;B1:D1;0))`